# A user asked a question, I commented on it and then they (supposedly) changed their username to match mine

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure what to think about this. I commented on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968865/get-list-from-string-with-exec-in-python) and let it go. After a while I returned to the question (as I usually do with questions I comment on) and I was surprised to see that the author of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968865/get-list-from-string-with-exec-in-python#comment100474980_56968865) was highlighted (which means it was written by OP) because it was my username.

It took me a second to realize that the OP changed their username to match mine. I'm pretty sure they had a different username at the time I posted my comment.

Did this user actually change their username to match mine (is this even possible?) or is this just a very weird bug?

**Just so it is clear:** I have nothing against that user and there was nothing "funny" going on in the comments I was just surprised to see "my" username highlighted in a comment I didn't write

Comment: Usernames are not unique. We can all be John Malkovich if we want to.

Comment: It's certainly possible, and it's way more likely that it's a weird user than that it's a weird bug.

Comment: It sure is some conspiracy ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ddKS.png

Comment: @rene How's that possible? Either editing or really it's a bug?

Comment: @Lighteninger I'm sure he just edited his personal DOM to take the screenshot.

Comment: Oh I remembered @TylerH I also did the same like opening console and edit variable to take the feel that I had 10k repo xD

Comment: @Lighteninger in your browser developer console execute:   `$('.comment-user').text('DeepSpace');`

Comment: That original question is a rollercoaster: someone edits out half the information, op approves the edit (which shouldn't have been approved imho), then edits in someone changed the question without their permission, then finally re-adds the code removed.

Comment: I have two name brothers on SO...

Comment: I enjoyed reading this.. funny users.. mystery solved. I guess this can be a reminder that we should all just be more chill and not to judge too quickly. :)

Comment: @Lighteninger Is it just a coincidence that you currently have 1,234 reputation right now?

Comment: @JL2210 Yup, it's right xD

Comment: The real question here is *why* are usernames not unique? What's the benefit to anybody?

Comment: @yivi Malkovich Malkovich? https://i.stack.imgur.com/luuEy.png

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm afraid you misremembered here. This account has used the display name `DeepSpace` since they first created it, several months ago. You can verify that they were using this same display name back in May by looking at [this earliest archived copy of their profile](http://web.archive.org/web/20190511154110/https://stackoverflow.com/users/11401689/deepspace).

Account display names (usernames) are not unique, and as long as there is nothing else going that might go against our [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) and [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), anything goes.

However, if you do see an account change their username to impersonate someone else (especially in response to comments or other interactions), then feel free to flag a post by that user account (or any of your own posts, if the user has no visible posts on our site) to bring this to moderator attention. We have much more information on accounts and can take various measures in case there is some kind of abuse going on, including resetting the name.

Comment: Will do. Just so it is clear: I have nothing against that user and there was nothing "funny" going on in the comments. I was just surprised to see "my" username highlighted in a comment I didn't write. Only my bad memory to blame for this post ;)

Comment: [nice try](https://gyazo.com/e2d4ca1a13133ef24747d51c06fcef9c)

Comment: So ordinary users have no other possibility, to see a user’s display name history, than web.archive.org?

Comment: @Holger: ordinary users are not given access to the account history, no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Did you really change your username just while posting this? Or is that some seriously good Photoshopping done by Alec?

Comment: @JL2210: I wouldn't [believe anything you see on the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhysU.png). Well, not when someone claims to have made a screenshot, at any rate..

Comment: @JL2210 - photoshop is not required. It's quite easy to change the contents of a web page on the client side via a browser's inspector tool.

Comment: @adam_0 [maybe](https://i.imgur.com/S7j7ngl.png) (I definitely don't do this to take images of my questions with thousands of votes).

Comment: One wonders what happens if you `@DeepSpace` on that question.

Comment: @Sirens What "unique" username?

Comment: "Account display names (usernames) are not unique"...  and here I thought I was special being the only dangel....  thanks for ruining my weekend

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's quite possible. As noted in the comments, usernames are not unique.

I've never had someone change their name to match mine, but I've see  multiple times where someone will change their name soon after asking a question. Usually they change it from a real name to a pseudo-name (worried about privacy maybe?) Maybe they wanted to change it quick before it was seen and got inspiration from you.

Comment: Once, right after I answered a question the asker changed their username to “monkeylove”. I still wonder if the change was brought up by my avatar or if it was pure coincidence.

Comment: @yivi I'm afraid we may never know the full story behind MonkeyLove.

Comment: _“Usually they change it from a real name to a pseudo-name”_ — the most (in)famous case is “[frosty](https://slate.com/technology/2013/10/silk-road-s-dread-pirate-ross-ulbricht-asked-stack-overflow-question-under-real-name.html?via=gdpr-consent)”.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I'll have to read that later if I had time. I just skimmed it. I never knew about that.

Comment: It's also worth noting that [changing the display name on a whim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26518/282465) is a potential SE network meme.

Comment: @yivi [Like this?](https://i.imgur.com/ytw9dWj.png)